# MySQL Many to many relation count query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

```
|TYPE      |  |REL_TABLE  |  |PRODUCT    |  
|----------|  |-----------|  |-----------|
|Id        |  |Id         |  |Id         |
|Title     |  |TypeId     |  |Name       | 
|CategoryID|  |ProductId  |
```

As you can see the the relations are TYPE.id -> REL_TABLE.TypeID and PRODUCT.Id -> REL_TABLE.ProductId

What i need is CategoryID and how many Product.Name there is to each CategoryID

Answer (score 0):

Just need to `JOIN` and `COUNT` results:

```
   SELECT t.CategoryID,
          COUNT(*)
    FROM TYPE as t
    LEFT JOIN REL_TABLE as r on t.Id = r.TypeId
         JOIN PRODUCT as p on p.id = r.ProductId
GROUP BY t.CategoryID
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `join and count` will do it along with `group by`

```
select t.categoryid, count(p.name)
from type t inner join rel_table rt on
t.id=rt.typeid inner join product p on
rt.productid=p.id
group by t.categoryid
```